# how to print dotted characters in PDF Document using ASP.net

Tags: .net

i am developing a small application using vb.net and asp.net here i have to generate pdf file from asp.net page which should contain words , the appearence of the letters of this word should be similar to ecofont please suggest a method to achieve this

thanks in advance

Comment: Embed a [dotted font?](http://www.searchfreefonts.com/categories/dotted.htm)

Comment: Two questions: 1) What exactly do you mean by "in dotted form"? and 
 2) How are you doing the rest of the character in the PDF document?  Are you using a library?  Or is your realy question 'How do I generate a PDF from .NET?"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [ecofont](http://www.ecofont.com/en/products/green/printing/sustainable-printing-using-ecofont-software.html)?

Comment: yes i expect similar to ecofont, but not exactly like that it should be like tracing letters i am using itextsharp dll

Comment: @svb123 Have you looked at the link Robert Harvey posted in a comment on your question (http://www.searchfreefonts.com/categories/dotted.htm)?  I'm not familiar with how to create dll's from C#, but his link seems to have a font that will suit your needs.